# Formatted Boot partition - cannot reinstall bootloader

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, windows-10

Ok, so ages ago I had 2 HDDs with 2 partitions each, one of which contained windows (7). Then I got an SSD added that, installed Win 8 on it and just ignored the fact that an unused win 7 was still on another partition. Later on I upgraded Win 8 to Win 10

Now today - like an idiot - I decided to format the unused Win 7 partition to clear up the space (and used a partitioning tool to force the formatting). Unfortunately it seems that the bootloader was still on that one and got lost in the process

Now I tried reinstalling it via a Win 8 Recovery Disc (it's the only one I can get my hands on at the moment), but I just can't get it to work. Here is what my partition table looks like:

[DiskPart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khxOj.jpg)

At this point E is the partition containing Windows 10, while D is the one that I formatted.

I tried:

- Using `bootrec /rebuildbcd` to recreate the BCD, but it always says, that it does not find any windows installations
- Using EasyRE, but it says, that there is no Windows on the selected partition
- Reinstalling the BCD via BootBCD, but it either does not work or I don't understand the command well enough to get it right.

Anything more I can do, to get it booting again? Any more Info needed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to get it done. The main problem seemed to be that I did in fact need to use the Windows 10 installer disc and not any older one.

With this one the following steps brought help:

- Set e: as active partition in DiskPart
- `bootbcd e:\windows /s e:`
- bootrec /rebuildbcd
- Reboot the installation disc
- Now you can actually use the built-in startup repair.

After going through all these motions, windows was back again